# Is the Dark Side of the Force more powerful?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

I was watching the battle between Obi-Wan and Anakin in Revenge of the Sith, and it struck me that most of the time Obi-Wan was getting pushed back by Anakin, and he only really got the upper hand after getting the higher ground.

I later found that:

1. [Darth Vitiate](http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Emperor) drained the life of his home planet
2. [Darth Sion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Sion) became immortal despite multiple mortal injuries and a broken body through his hatred
3. [Darth Sidious](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_storm_(wormhole)) could produce a hyperspace wormhole that could destroy entire planets
4. [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis) could apparently create new life from the force

Considering these feats it seems clear that the Dark Side is vastly superior in terms of power. However, Yoda doesn't seem to think so when he tells Luke in the [Empire Strikes Back](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000015/quotes):

> Luke: Vader... Is the dark side stronger?
>
> Yoda: No, no, no. Quicker, easier, more seductive.

Comment: I think that the Dark Force users just push it harder. I'm pretty sure someone like Yoda would be able to make such achievements if he decided to and stuidied to do so. It's the typical good/bad seen in different universes (e.g., Harry Potter [Dumbledore/Voldemort], The Lord of the Rings [Gandalf/Sauron]).

I ultimately think it's a matter of decency and knowing where to stop.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - Yes, commiting atrocities against the Force doesn't make you stronger

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Are Sith stronger than Jedi?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75638/5184)

Comment: @phantom42 I think the difference between my question and his is that I'm looking at feats. Someone could objectively answer my question by saying "Yes, the light side has no feats at that level" or "No, XXXX light side user performed this feat". Whereas that question asked about the results of duels between Sith and Jedi which is hit and miss: Sometimes Jedi win, and sometimes Sith win.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't VTC.

Comment: Ah, appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Much of the downfall of the Jedi was due to their arrogance.  They were sure they had everything under control and nothing could occur without them knowing.  Granted, Yoda was smarter than that and commented several times about Jedi arrogance and their blindness.  Nevertheless, it is conceivable that Yoda is not being objective when he says the dark side is not stronger.

Comment: Off-topic, but what exactly is *Twilight Sparkle* going to do with this knowledge? I'm worried.

Comment: Let us not forget that one Sith was physically immortal, but several Jedi was spiritually immortal. Which is better? Depends on your point of view. But in someways I have to agree that to help movie plots it seems old GL made the Dark side more sinister, more powerful so that 2 could beat many. Better for story lines.  But then the same person gave R2D2 certain abilities in the "older" movies that he never had in Episode 4-6 (like rockets to fly, etc) and in Ep 4 Kenobi does not remember the droids that he spend so much time with and C3PO also knows nothing of their previous lives.

Comment: Don't forget that in The Clone Wars cartoons, General Grievous took on several Jedi at once and killed quite a few of them.  And he wasn't even a Sith, he was still an apprentice training under Count Dooku.  Plus, the fact that Darth Sidious made a cloud of... something ... that the Jedi couldn't pierce.  Palpatine: Master Yoda, do you really think it will come to war?  Yoda: Hmmm. The Dark Side clouds everything. Impossible to see, the future is.

Comment: The Rule of Two may play into this.  If there are thousands of Jedi using the light side, but only two Sith using the dark side, the latter might have more power to draw upon.

Comment: I'm not an expert in the canon; however, in what I have seen, only those who died aligned with the Light would go on to live as spirits. Could it be that the Dark side can destroy, but only the light side has the potential for eternal life?

Comment: Well, for someone who wants power the dark side is the way to go. That's hardly news. The light side isn't about power, it's about being a force for good.

Comment: Seems like a pretty opinion based question

Comment: Seems to me that some Sith are very powerful, such as Sidious, Plaugueis, et. al. This does not mean that the dark side is stronger, only some users are. These users then slaughter other Sith, because of the rule of two. If you are a Sith lord, Jedi are hardly your prime concern, it's other Sith lords who will seek you out and either dominate, or kill you, or you them.  Sith arts usually depend on _coercion_ which is the tool of the evildoer. They don't live in harmony with the Force, they manipulate it, and are slain by others who prefer such manipulations.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

As with many questions about the Force, the answer depends on a **certain point of view**.

Yoda says that the dark side is not stronger. However, you note several feats performed by Sith that are far more powerful than anything we've seen Jedi do with the light side of the force. In addition, there the lightsaber duels. Darth Maul is beaten by Obi-wan, but he kills Qui-gon in the process. And, as DVK observes, when Anakin defeated Dooku, Mace Windu bested Palpatine, and when Luke beat Vader, they all did so by using the anger and aggression of the dark side. This leaves Obi-wan's victory over Anakin and possibly Count Dooku fleeing from Yoda as the only "pure" light side wins, and in both cases the Jedi combatant is much more experienced than his opponent. So, it appears that the dark side *is* stronger, despite what Yoda says.

However, Yoda is unlikely to think of strength solely in terms of winning fights or destroying enemies. He is probably referring to the ability to influence events, in addition to what could be called "strength of character". Looking at events from **this** point of view, they seem to support his statement.

Mace Windu's Vaapad fighting style was based on *controlling* his aggression, and was explicitly a light-side technique.

When Anakin fought Dooku, Dooku went easy on him in an attempt to get him to use his anger, so that he might be turned to the dark side. It worked. I doubt that Yoda would consider Anakin becoming a Sith Lord a "win".

Palpatine and Vader tried the same thing against Luke. He beat Vader in a lightsaber fight because he was *supposed* to. Darth Vader spent most of his time taunting Luke, urging him to give in to his anger. Even when they were fighting, Vader didn't attack much. Luke's real victory was **not** attacking in anger and cutting off Vader's hand; it was refusing to give in and kill him. This was a "light-side" act. It let not only to the defeat of the Emperor, but also to Anakin's redemption -- something that the dark side **never** could have achieved.

Similarly, when Obi-wan fought Darth Vader for the last time, he was not trying to "win" in the traditional sense. He was buying time for the others. He also didn't resist when Vader struck the killing blow. So, in a sense, he lost, but as a result, he was able to continue to mentor Luke, and even provide an example for Luke's eventual decision not to fight.

So, what Yoda told you was true, *from a certain point of view*.

Comment: Yes. What's more powerful: a nuclear bomb, or love? Physics says the first; Yoda would probably say the latter.

Comment: @PaulDraper And Dumbledore would agree! But that comparison is not really relevant to this discussion - in-universe this question boils down to "What's more powerful? Love or Hate? Peace or Anger?" what with Love/Peace and Anger/Hate being the respective fuels for the "Sides" of the Force.

Comment: @Shisa, sort of. Hate (in one way or another) created an atom bomb. Hate "produced a hyperspace wormhole that could destroy entire planets." The OP is asking, "Hey look at all these totally powerful things hate/anger/the Dark side has done. The light side's got nothing that powerful." Well, speaking in megatons, true. KSmarts says Yoda isn't thinking in megatons. He's thinking bigger.

Comment: @Shisa The short version is, in the current canon of Anakin Skywalker/Darth Vader's life, the light side wins.

Comment: @PaulDraper Love is a very powerful force. Even moreso when it's focused into a coherent beam of destruction.

Comment: @PaulDraper (I'm nitpicking!) Of course physics doesn't say a nuclear bomb is more powerful than love. Physics would say "that's an ill-defined comparison. First, determine which 'power' you are talking about. Energy release maybe? Then define the time period over which we're measuring. And then -- and this is the kicker -- define 'love'" ;) (btw, I'm still voting the Sith are more powerful, if misunderstood :P )

Comment: @Andres, for physics, love is a pattern of electrical signals in the brain. Defining it precisely is difficult, but putting upper limits on its rate of energy expenditure is not. A back-of-the-envelope calculation shows even a modestly sized nuclear bomb to be more powerful.

Comment: @PaulDraper Indeed, that seems to paint love in a bad light. Oh, well, physics doesn't lie, so I guess I'll give my wife an atom bomb for our next anniversary, since it's demonstrably more powerful than love :D

Comment: @PaulDraper, I have to politely disagree. With respect to energy output, love inspires the expenditure of personal energy over time in the people in which it inhabits. Let's assume a 20 Kiloton nuclear device; that's 83,680,000 megajoules of energy. An average human on the low end of the scale uses 0.225 megajoules per hour. So for a single person to match the energy, it would take 371,911,112 hours. But every person this affects cuts the time down. Inspire every US citizen (322 million) and we'll burn 72,489,818 Mj an hour. _**An hour**_. Inspire the world and put the nuke to _**SHAME**_.

Comment: This answer is good, but it misses some points. Primarily, of course, canon now contains plenty of examples of light side adherents winning in combat. But more to the point: while the dark side can provide immediate superiority in combat to those who tap into it (as we see with Luke, Anakin, and Rey), it has some serious weaknesses (such as the inability to retain one’s identity in the Force after death, and becoming so consumed with hatred that one becomes almost foolish). *That* is what Yoda means when he says it’s quicker and easier. Tactics vs. strategy.

Comment: Is it a bit like a person with a knife? A good person can cut their bread, but an evil one has power over life and death.

Answer (score 67):

The Dark Side *seems* more powerful because Dark Side users don't restrict themselves in what they do with the Force as per the examples in the question - my take has always been that the Jedi etc could achieve effects of the same magnitude but *choose not to*.

Comment: Agreed. But that also means that the answer to his question would be.. in theory: no, in practice: yes.

Comment: Thing is, if I'm allowed to kick you in the balls and cut your throat while you're on the ground, but you _choose not to do that_, then I'll win every time. And it won't matter how strong you could have been or what heroic deeds you might have done if you you lived.

Comment: @Damon: In a fight between a murderer and a pacifist, I could see describing the murderer as "more powerful".  He has no restrictions limiting his power.

Comment: Something that the other answers regarding the EU have glossed over is Dorsk 81 sacrificing his life to physically hurl 17 Star Destroyers out of a Solar System. This is a pretty crazy use of the Force, and I would argue that there is no real comparison to this by the Dark Side anywhere in the EU. But it clearly demonstrates what you are talking about in this post.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't know that the analogy is quite right though, as the Jedi are obviously *not* pacifists.

Comment: @Mark: That is an amazing feat

Comment: Hmm seems that Dorsk 81 couldn't do it alone; he was standing on a Force Apex and had the force poured into him by all the other Jedi.

Comment: @Damon: Let's say your opponent is a master Shaolin, who could kick you across the courtyard all day if he chose to do so. But when you kick his balls and cut his throat, he *decides* not to defend himself out of some spiritual conviction of his. That doesn't make your *fight style* stronger than his.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, while you may be willing to kick his balls and cutting his throat (and have the power to do so), landing that kick or getting close enough to the master may be impossible due to the magnitude of his power.

Comment: @Devsolar : Thing is, in this comparison, we are **both** Shaolin masters, only I'll kick you in the balls without hesitating, whereas your code of honour forbids doing so. I also won't hestitate picking up a gun, or poisoning your food. Or kill you while you sleep.

Comment: @Damon: To continue down that metaphor road, while the kicking-in-the-balls approach *might* swing the balance in your favor in a one-on-one, me being liked and having friends *might* swing the balance in my favor in general. Neither has any influence on our respective Shaolin styles -- we're still *both* masters. Your willingness to do things I won't do doesn't give you an advantage without disadvantages to go with it.

Comment: @Mark: Whoa!  I only know about Dorsk 81 from the _Jedi Academy Trilogy_, where he is (IMO) underdeveloped.  Where does the adventure you refer to happen?

Comment: @CodeswithHammer It's in [DarkSaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber_(novel)). Don't read it, it's awful.

Answer (score 34):

I believe it's worth noticing that Yoda never said the Light side is **stronger**. He just stated that the dark side **is not**. This could lead us to assume that in terms of strength, both are equal.

The point is the source of strength is essentially the same, the Force. What would vary is the knowledge one has of it, and the techniques one develops from it.

Imagine a cop and a criminal, both using the same kind of gun. None of them has more firepower than the other, but the training and ability one of them has with the gun may define a winner.

It's been discussed before how the Jedi got sloppy in the years without noticing the Sith were around. So, for example, Yoda lost the duel against Sidious, not because the Dark Side is stronger, but because Sidious was, at that point, a more developed Force user than Yoda.

Answer (score 17):

To expand on PhilPursglove's answer:

You've answered your own question.  Since we only have the canon to use as sources, No, the Dark Side is ***not*** strong.

> Yoda: Yes, run! Yes, a Jedi's strength flows from the Force. But
>   beware of the dark side. Anger, fear, aggression; the dark side of the
>   Force are they. Easily they flow, quick to join you in a fight. If
>   once you start down the dark path, forever will it dominate your
>   destiny, consume you it will, as it did Obi-Wan's apprentice.
>
> Luke: Vader. Is the dark side stronger?
>
> Yoda: No, no, no. Quicker, easier, more seductive.
>
> Luke: But how am I to know the good side from the bad?
>
> Yoda: You will know... when you are calm, at peace, passive. A Jedi
>   uses the Force for knowledge and defense, *never* for attack.

It should also be noted that the Dark and Light are aspects of the same mystical energy field.

There is at least two abilities that we have only seen Dark Side wielders use (force lightning, force choke).  This does not necessarily mean Light Side users are unable to use these abilities, it may be an instance of them being *unwilling* to do so.

---

If you want to include Legends/EU:

Darth Plagueis indicated that lightning is only something available to Dark Force users, since Dark Force users accept the consequences of the use and reject compassion for their victims.

But... Luke is able to use a green-colored variant in *Dark Nest I: The Joiner King*

Comment: hmm, and not one mention of midichlorianianianianisms. :c)

Comment: actually you see luke use the force choke in return of the jedi, also the force choke itself isnt a special move that is dark or light, it is simply using the force to squeeze someones throat, similar to using it to lift an apple. also choking someone to the point they pass out is a very effective non-lethal combat practice, used by the military, and cops (who then accidentally choke people to death but whatever lol)

Comment: @Himarm Oh, right, in Jabba's palace.

Comment: -1 for blindly believing propaganda from the loser Yoda. If it's not stronger, then why did 2 Sith manage to exterminate entire Jedi order?

Comment: @DVK, Sidious used politics and conspiracy to eradicate the Jedi.  Most were killed via Order 66.  Although that leads to the question as to why most of the Jedi were unable to sense their CloneTroopers' betrayal and survive.  Or why the Jedi could not sense the bigger conspiracy.  This is never truly answered in movie canon, although the EU talks about "Force Concealment", which apparently not only did Sidious use to hide his power, but Yoda and Kenobi also used to hide from the Empire.  Vader, meanwhile, slaughtered Younglings (the coward).

Comment: @scott.korin - plenty of Jedi were killed by Vader/Anakin. Or Sidious himself who dispatched 3 of them and only stumbled on borderline-Dark Vaapad of Windu. And before killing the "younglings", Anakin/Vader dispatched a **lightsaber instructor** in the Temple, named "Troll" (this is new canon)

Comment: "A Jedi uses the Force for knowledge and defense, never for attack." I my eyes, this quote explains the battle referenced in the question. Obi Wan is getting pushed around a bit because he's fighting defensively; the fact he didn't get outright slaughtered is evidence of his comparable power.

Comment: In the Clone Wars cartoon Anakin uses the Force to choke people for information one or two times. I saw this as evidence of his growing darkness. But I don't see it as more Dark than the time he and a Jedi master used the Force to do mental invasion. Which the light Jedi apparently do *all the time*.

Comment: @scott.korin My guess as to why more Jedi didn't sense the betrayal of the Clone Troopers is their actions weren't bourn out of malice. They were merely following orders they were bred to follow.

Comment: About the lightning part of the answer: In clone wars yoda comments a bit on that and from how he talks about it it seems like he IS capable of producing force lightning but is choosing not to and instead only dissipates it when he got attacked with it.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe There's a simpler explanation. They were focusing on the battle and their enemies, and they trusted their allies. Most of them were in active combat, iirc. Yoda had several things going for him which allowed him to sense it ahead of time: he was overseeing instead of participating, he was in a relatively safe location, and he actually sensed the deaths of several Jedi before he was attacked.

Comment: The idea I get is that the Jedi learn to use the Force while the Sith learn to access the Force but to use their emotions. The Sith are constantly telling the Jedi they are trying to turn to give into their anger/hatred etc. and it makes sense. If you take a self defense class and throw a punch, it's a punch. If you get mad and throw a punch, you can put your fist through a wall. In that way, it seems like the anger/hate etc. of the Dark side acts as a kind of "steroids" for the Force.

Comment: Why do Jedi *choose not to* use lightning, given that it could arguably be useful to their cause? Because it's a *dark side power*, which means that to conjure it you have to be using the dark side. The way of the Jedi is opposed to deliberate, conscious use of the dark side.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, as your own questions' examples indicate, the Dark Side is clearly far more powerful **if you include EU/Legends canon**, since its adherents were able to perform Force-based feats that were superior to anything Light Side adherents could/did (including functional immortality of many Sith Masters up to Sidious, which was the counter to Jedi's Force Ghost thing).

---

Despite Yoda's brainwashing of Luke on Dagobah, the Dark Side is also shown to be more powerful according to **main Disney canon**, as in any direct confrontation between Light and Dark side, the Dark side worn on sheer power (Yoda vs. Sidious, especially as shown in the Novelization where they note Yoda openly admitting to himself he was outclassed).

The only time there was a balance or a win for Light side was when - according to ROTS novelization - Mace Windu used Vaapad, which bordered on Dark side - to fight Sidious.

The only way Anakin (supposedly, the most powerful Force user at the time with the highest *Midichlorian* count) managed to prevail over a Sith **Apprentice** Tirannus was by tapping into Dark Side. Luke was hopelessly outclassed against the Emperor and only won via Vader's treachery.

Comment: I'm off to the washroom to try and feel less dirty after using the M-word in my answer.

Comment: Speaking specifically to your claim of immortality, I have to disagree, as Ood Bnar managed to live (dramatically) longer then any Dark Side user of note in the EU.

Comment: @Mark - that may have had more to do with him being a member of tree-like species that had a naturally long lifespan, than being a Light Side user. I'm referring to Old Timey Sith Lords consciousness arising again in Republic time. Or Sidious's second rising.

Comment: So is Obi-wan v. Anakin not a direct confrontation between Light and Dark side? Does Dooku running away from Yoda not count as a win for Yoda?

Comment: @KSmarts OB1 vs Anakin is direct, but Obi-Wan won by being superior swordfighter (better tactics) not superior Force user. Dooku wasn't in Yoda's league, he was the apprentice, not the Master. And his main reason to run was because he had to deliver Death Star plans to Bail Organa... errr... Darth Sidious

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like a "no true Scotsman" argument. Dark beats Light, except when it doesn't, but those times don't count? Anyway, I had way too much to say in response, so I just made my own answer.

Comment: @KSmarts - When you do science, you try to arrange things *ceterus parabus*. All other things being equal. If you compare power of Dark and Light side, the only valid experiment is when both users are of top power AND both specifically show their Force power (and not cunning, smarts, tactics or inborn biological ability)

Comment: You are using Disney CANON!?

Comment: @Virusboy - You did not see me using Disney canon *waves hand*

Comment: @DVK in your answer to KSmarts  comment on the fight there is something that is not taken into account. Star wars 2 Yoda indicates that the combat with lightsaber is the ultimate test to how powerful the two combatants are with the force (as he drew his lightsaber against dooku). Thus the lightsaber combat using the full power of a force user in combat.

Answer (score 11):

No, one side of the Force is not more powerful then the other.  This is because it is the same Force, just manipulated differently and often for different purposes.

That being said, in most cases I am aware of (with the exception of the video games) the Force users who are dark aligned are more powerful.  There are a number of reasons for this:

- It is easier to destroy then create.
- Dark users are not worried about the consequences of their actions except to gain power.
- Greater Force power can be exerted using stronger (and harder to control emotions) like hate and love.
- Dark users training usually focuses on combat and power.

The Knights of the Old Republic (KOTOR) provides a good analogy, allowing all players to learn any Force power, but requiring more energy/effort to use it if you are not [aligned](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic/Alignment#Force_powers) to it.

Comment: You should note that the Knights of the Republic Novel Revan specifically addresses this - with Revan 'discovering' that his powerful Love emotion is able to be channeled into his LIGHT side Force power.

Answer (score 11):

Both canon and EU consistently portray dark siders as accomplishing far grander feats than light siders. In single combat prowess, I would say they are evenly matched. In Force powers, there seems to be a clear difference. The examples you give include destruction of a whole planet's population: Even healing one sick person is considered impressive light side mastery. How shocking would it be to see a light side user heal a whole planet, let alone bring a whole planet's worth of corpses to life? The biggest comparable light side feat is becoming a Force ghost, which seems like it would fall a bit short of, for instance, rivaling Darth Sion's accomplishment.

I think this is also unavoidable in a sense. For one, choosing the dark side carries many disadvantages already (everyone hates you, you take a CON penalty...). Why would anyone choose it unless it actually offered some benefit in return? Furthermore, it is hardly heroic or even interesting for a powerful force of good crush a weaker evil, so it wouldn't (didn't?) make for much of a story.

However, individual power is not the same as collective power. The Jedi have values favoring peaceful coexistence, harmony and cooperation. Thus all Jedi are naturally dependable allies of each other. Meanwhile, if you lock two Sith in a room, one won't be walking out.

The Sith are not only powerful, but also aggressive and disdainful of restraint. So a society ruled by Sith would have inherent inefficiencies: Either the Sith would constantly fight each other, or they would be unable to actually exercise their powers for fear of triggering mutually assured destruction. The familiar nuclear bomb seems analogous in power to the legendary Sith draining a whole planet - yet how many nations use nuclear bombs in combat? The only exception occurred when there was precisely one nation capable of using them.

A lot of this discussion, both in-universe and between fans, seems to deal with the individual. Who fights better, who has more political status, who has sicker Force powers, who comes out on top in the end. But the supposed great triumphs of the Sith are largely enabled by a dominance of the Jedi. When Sith are dominant, they fare far less impressively.

Comment: One point to consider though. Vader and the emperor. Both were in the same room quite often and the emperor ruled with vader by his side quite long. Both walked out of the room for almost 20 years

Comment: @Thomas That's true. Sith seem to be depicted most often as scheming, dishonorable fellows. I wonder how it came to be that those two powerful Sith never tried to become the sole authority of a galactic empire for decades. Perhaps Anakin had some kind of psychological dependence on Palpatine (established in his youth), and lacked the initiative to consider living his own life without his guidance? Also, notably, this was the first pair of Siths that were written, and I believe many details of the setting were not yet established.

Comment: One possibility could be that anakin lost his will to dominate after padmes death. And only regained it when he met his son (but was not strong enough by then to overthrow the emperor). That could explain why he did not try before but offered it to luke in the empire strikes back. (From how it was indicated in the films the emperor did not share the rulership with vader. vader was just his lackey all those years)

Comment: +1 Though I'm not necessarily in agreement with saying that a sith society is inherently more inefficient. The sith empire was pretty efficient, and the emperor of that empire accomplished great feats. Other siths during that time also made great feats.

Comment: @Superbest, in the EU Vader did try to supplant Palpatine. The Force Unleashed video games show this. Vader was just afraid that Palpatine was too powerful for him to take down alone. Vader also shows extreme caution, to the point of being a coward, when it comes to fighting Palpatine directly.

Comment: `However, individual power is not the same as collective power.` This, IMO, is the core element of most Good vs. Evil stories -- the champions of Good have the ability to work together for a larger purpose; the champions of Evil never place the collective purpose above their own interests.  (I note in passing that as I understand it, Sidious's grand plan was to make the Sith Order's purpose of Galactic conquest his personal achievement.)

Answer (score 10):

It is very possible (however not verified, because we have not seen any events created by non-dark jedi that are equal to the powers we have seen done by the dark side) that the force has a breaking point which there is constantly conflict. We constantly see Yoda referring to the dark force as the dark **side** of the force; not as the dark force.

We can there conclude that either the force is divided between the sides and is static, or that the barrier is being changed based on some other factor. From that, and based on how Yoda describes the dark side of the force as *"quicker* and *"easier"* we may conclude that the dark side is just more exploitable and also mush easier to create such events, which would be harder to do as a Jedi. You can from there determine that the powers are equal, but the Jedi use the force with peace, and the Sith use the force with anger, hatred, etc. (Or you could say that it is not the force itself that is more powerful at all... just the people who wield it)

Something notable is that, in general, anger and hate lead to more impact (in real life) than passivity and peace do. (or at least appear to do)

This may be a possible answer to as why the dark side appears to be more powerful.

Comment: Hi not bad for a 1st answer. Next time try adding some link as where do you get these quotes :)

Comment: I like your last bit. And in real life we see it. Countries that have peace and justice (Light Side) develop powerful economies, higher technologies and their impact is felt around the world via their culture. Violent repressive countries may have a powerful wealthy ruling elite, but have trouble building their own tanks and jets.

Answer (score 4):

I am no canon expert -- so I would love this to be sharpshot by someone more intimate with the details. (In particular, I have no knowledge of book material, and wouldn't know which books are considered canon, or even relevant, even if I read one.)

There is an apparent problem of balance, in particular the prophecy that relates to Anakin indicates that his role will be to return "balance to the force". This indicates that things are out of balance for the majority of the story bits we see in the movies.

While the characters in the story tend to assume that this means something "good" will happen (enhancing the strength of the light side), it certainly appears that the force was unbalanced in the opposite direction and Anakin's role in restoring balance was to obliterate most of what the light side seemed to have going for it.

The near annihilation of the Jedi makes me wonder if part of the balance issue means there is a sort of universal quantity to the force aside from the number of individuals aligned one way or the other, and some distribution of this universal quantity then affects the force sensitive folks who are scattered about. In this case, then the *entire* dark side is focused on just two serious users at a time (the Sith pair), making their individual force potential overwhelmingly greater than any given light-aligned Jedi who are merely parceled out whatever is their active tappable amount of force energy after distribution across all the other tens or hundreds of Jedi wandering around.

In this latter case, then the force is always in universal balance, but the distribution or concentration of it is what is unbalanced, and it would be natural to find that the strength of any given Sith is generally greater than that of any given Jedi. But then why was Kenobi able to beat Vader at all, if not just for Skywalkers lack of experience, despite his superior power?

Comment: Finally! I've been saying the same about "balance in the force" for ages. The entire Jedi order against two of the sith. That seems to be unbalanced. On the other hand I don't think the "evenly distributed" part is right see [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79318/33716) about that. The dark side is simply more effective (while not necessarily stronger). Also Kenobi was able to beat Vader because Vader wasn't well-trained in light saber combat. That duel was not decided by the force, it was decided by combat practice.

Comment: @mg30rg Perhaps "more effective" in this sense is that it is very combat/impact oriented, while the range of light side skills may be more broad. Meaning, perhaps, that one must master a wide range of mundane knowledge in addition to the force to utilize the breadth of the light side, while the dark side is perhaps more narrowly focused. Or something like that. I'm essentially proposition a skill-breadth analog to my population-breadth discussion above. I would love a serious canon expert to sharpshoot the both of us.

Comment: Anakin brought balance to the force in the most straightforward way imaginable.  Look at the sequence of events: as Darth Vader, he helps eliminate the Jedi order, but leaves exactly two Jedi alive.  Sixteen-odd years later, Luke starts to learn to use the light side, so bam! Vader kills Obi-Wan.  Pretty much the same day IIRC.  In the third movie, Yoda dies, so *of course* Vader has to kill the Emperor.  Balance!  (Granted, Anakin's death messes that up, as does his presumed conversion to the light side shortly beforehand.  But nobody's perfect.) :-)

Comment: The balance of the Force is *not* the balance of the Force-users; Force-users are not the Force. It is not a Jedi and Sith head count.

Answer (score 4):

Answering differently

Xkcd shows a feature of both sides using the force (though more focus on Yoda) and calculates the energy. 
The result is both are similar;

[How much Force power can Yoda output?](https://what-if.xkcd.com/3/)

Yoda lifting a x-wing uses 19.2 kW and
The Emperor zapping Luke uses 10kW,

Comment: Link-only answers tend to be frowned upon. I'm not downvoting, but you should edit in at least some of the information provided in the link.

Answer (score 3):

The Dark Side is **not** more powerful. It's just more flashy, and the power comes easier. Not everything is about lightsaber combat.

What this means is that a novice in the Dark Side might seem to advance more quickly than a novice in the Light Side. However, as they progress, the Light Side Jedi should come to a deeper understanding of the living force, able to draw on more power for things like healing and knowledge.

Put another way, a Dark Side Force user might be able to win a straight-up lightsaber duel in a fair fight, such as an arena situation. But a Light Side Jedi would use a deeper understanding of the Force to defeat the Dark Side Jedi before the battle even begins, if indeed it ever even needed to be fought, by understanding and adapting to or controlling the situation before ever entering the fight in the first place. And I'm not willing to concede that Lightsaber duel just yet. A Dark Side Force user might jump higher, but the Light Side user would allow the Force to guide him to just the right stance to be ready when jump is over. A Dark Side user might make bigger and stronger attacks, but the Light Side user would be able to put up just the blocks he needs, and over time wear down his opponent.

Another example is intuition. I think one of the overlooked powers of a Jedi is that they'd be a natural at whatever task they attempted. A Jedi that feels the guidance of the Force would almost instinctively pick up the best way to accomplish a task, allowing them to fit in with almost any profession. I think a Light Side Jedi would be better at this than the a follower of the Dark Side.

All this helps explain how a relatively small number of Jedi are able to be the peacekeepers of the entire Galaxy for so long: they are always exactly where they need to be, led there by the Force. The Empire, symbol of the Dark Side's dominance over the Light Side, lasts a scant 18 years. It's just a blip compared to the Jedi's 1000 generations as the galaxy's peace keepers, and you could argue that even this blip only comes to be because of some vague prophecy or need in the Force to bring some balance.

Of course, there were also the Sith Empire and other Dark Side incursions in the Expanded Universe even greater than the Empire. However, remember that these were all eventually defeated by the Light Side.

Answer (score 2):

The dark side of the Force is like the Force's shadow, it may seem longer, bigger, stronger, but in reality it fades away when a light is turned on. I agree with Yoda, it is quicker, easier, and more seductive to use the Force's shadow and not have to live like a Jedi or do what the Force tells me and just do whatever I want, like destroying a planet, or bringing back the dead, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think all of you are missing the point here: the whole messing around the force in SW is about evolution. There are regular people (not certainly humans) and there is a new niche of evolution: force sensitive people. The new, more advanced people with the (fairly limited) ability to directly sense and manipulate the forces that control the universe. What do you think celibacy is for in the Jedi order? They wish to prevent this new breed of people taking over by breeding between each other or weakening their bloodline and sharing this power by breeding with regular people.

Sith however is the "shit in the fan". An even stronger breed of people a newer niche of evolution who can sense and manipulate the forces that control the universe more instictively. Two sith against the entire Jedi Order means a balance of the force. What does it tell? Of course they (the Jedi Order) wish to keep this blooming new breed under control because they know how evolution works: the survival of the fittest would esily wipe out jedis from the universe. That is why Yoda and other Jedi masters preventing apprentices from practicing the "dark side", and also that is the reason they "hunt down" force sensitive people of their universe and enlist them in their (kind of fascist) order. That is how I see Jedi.

And let's the downvoting begin!

/*Also, please convince me I'm not right! All further downvoters please leave a meaningful comment on the reason of the downvote. (A good reason is when you have an in- or out universe source that I am wrong, proofs, commentaries etc. A bad reason is downvoting because you disagree. Grow up already. :D I may ruin a fairy tale which bleeds from a thousand wounds but at least I provide an objective standpoint.) */

Comment: Though this is certainly the way things often play out in the real world, I am curious if there are any references to this concept in the stories? Either Lucas (or a writer, or someone else authorized to wield the canon) thought along these lines himself at one point, or the manifestation of some of these story/social artifacts is just an uncontemplated reflection of our own historical reaction to such situations included to add flavor and familiarity -- but I have no idea which. Anyway, interesting view.

Comment: Thank you. AFAIK there is no in-universe reference to my point of view, but all in-unverse events (including extended universe) points into this direction.

Comment: No downvote, but this answer doesn't seem to make sense.  You're talking about two different unrelated types of evolution - regular people vs force users, and then Sith vs Jedi.  The first is biological, the second is philosophical.  Both can be thought of in terms of evolution, but they're not related to each other like you imply.

Comment: @DanSmolinske - I don't think it would be two different sort of evolution. Though it is never mentioned in-universe I strongly doubt every jedi has the potential to become a sith.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that neither is stronger, and to arrive at this answer requires considering the philosophies of the two sides.  The Force doesn't actually have two sides; people do.  Traits associated with the dark and light side are traits that all people have, in balance or with favor to one side or the other.  The only reason it seems that the Force has two sides is that the individual balance of those traits is expressed through something much more obvious and powerful in those who wield it.

Read the Jedi Code, the Sith Code, and even the new Disney canon.  Or just be a little reasonable in recognizing that a story can not have good and bad guys without diametrically opposed philosophies.  Or just notice that the Force user's manifestation of their abilities is influenced strongly by their temperament and the philosophy they follow.

Arnaud Huet, also on this page, is correct.  Jedi and Sith are not shaped by the Force so much as they shape themselves.  That was the moral of the story when Vader redeemed himself, and it resonates throughout every single one of the films.  They're not slaves to the Force.  Their use of it is an expression and extension of who they are.

Those who say that Light Side users of the Force could do the same things and simply choose not to, are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In some occurrences, the Dark Side may seem more powerful than the light side, and it occasionally is.

But you have a strong bias favoring the dark side.

First point is the rule of two. The apprentice has to be stronger than his master. I don't think many masters died of old age.
Apprentices must have a huge attrition rate, between the death in training and the deaths when you try to overpower your master.
So on average Sith are far stronger than Jedi, because the weak and the stupid had died before they can fight any Jedi.
More over, Jedi do not only select the most powerful beings.

Second point, Jedi receive far less training or at least far less specific training. They are the space police. They do not focus 100% of their time to the objective of destroying their opponents.

Third point, the Jedi do not need to do any show of force in order to dominate the Galaxy. Sith rules through fear. So they have to appear almighty. Otherwise they are dead meat.

The Jedi have shown incredible capabilities. Yoda was able to block force moves from some of the most powerful force users you ever got to see.

In legends, Luke and Leia killed Palpatine using his own force tempest.
Luke and Vader apprentice did crash Star destroyers on planets.
Luke's apprentices sent flying away a fucking star destroyer fleet.
The Jedi were proven to be able to cut someone from the Force, and to wipe people memories.

Ok, we did not see the Jedi curing a whole planet, or some impressive feats like that.
Curing a people is incredibly more complex than absorbing his life. And as everyone different, curing a bunch of people may prove impossible unless you are the Force itself.
It may require you to inject some energy instead of taking it.

In the Palpatine/Yoda duel, you can still see than Sidious fears Yoda, even while he is probably the most powerful Sith Lord ever.
So this proves than Jedi are totally able to fight Sith as equals. 
Jedi are mainly using defensive abilities, so a Jedi equally experienced and powerful than a Sith would likely nullify his opponents power.
And the victory would be gained by a lightsaber battle.

Sith Lords may have been really powerful and doing incredible things. Do not forget one simple truth, they have always been defeated at one point.

Actually, light Side is stronger, because the Dark Side feed upon itself. It consume his users, breaking their dominion.

Moreover, if you want to dominate the Galaxy you have to dominate or be allied with all the force users. They are stronger than the force users.

Common people are natural allies to the light Side. So the values coming with the light Side are indeed powerful enough to defeat the Dark Side.
Moreover, even if the Jedi were to disappear, the fight for their values and freedom would continue.

Whereas no one would fight for dead Sith. Therefore, the Light Side might be temporarily suppressed, but it will never be defeated and it will dominate the Galaxy most of the time.

UPDATE :

Actually in legends it seems that Luke was able to create small black holes and holograms. I don't know the original source but I found this [SE link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/why-didnt-yoda-and-obi-wan-kill-darth-vader-and-the-emperor-why-wait-for-skywa)

Answer (score -2):

I think there is ultimately no Dark side or Light side to the force itself.
The force is and its user learn to channel it.
The dark side is full of passion and therefore knows no boundaries nor limits, it grows fast, it is fulfilling emotionally but destructive while on the other hand the light side is all about the control, the calculated usage, the dominion over the force itself, the abolition of emotions.

No side is better or stronger, jedis are emotionless control freaks while siths are crazy drug-addicts

Comment: According to George Lucas, the energy field of the Force has both a good side and a bad side. That's the *Force* he's talking about, as opposed to a person.