# Did any Jedi in the Old Republic employ prostitutes?

Tags: star-wars

In the New Jedi Order, Jedi can get married, have children, the whole shabang. Jedi in the Old Order, however cannot, as it is believed physical attachment can lead to the Dark Side. Does this mean no hiring of prostitutes, because it is one thing to not get emotionally attached to a prostitute and a different thing entirely to fall in love with someone? Any mention in EU or legends, anyone?

Comment: Desire and lust are also quite dark emotions that Jedi try to overcome so I really, really doubt.

Comment: Also, ew. Just ... Ew

Comment: Actually Old Order jedi went back and forth on the whole marriage thing. Even when they decried it, however, they still continued to do it.

Comment: Who knows... When Windu didn't care about *Killing isn't Jedi way*, well you can think...

Comment: @Peter Yeah, but people still do it. I imagine that based off of the activities of the Skywalkers and other Jedi that they are people too, with desires and needs that must either be suppressed or somehow dealt with.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan A bunch of incredibly fit men and women who aren't allowed to marry get lumped up into a few enclaves. [Where have I heard of this before?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_Village)

Comment: Maybe Valenthyne Farfalla ;)

Comment: Remember how Ahsoka was disguised as a slave for a mission? I learnt this from a different universe, but I think it applies: The art of deception requires you to learn even the ways of your enemies and those whom you find morally offending, sometimes precisely so that you can right these wrongs. Going by that logic, if employing prostitutes and engaging in the act can help the greater good...

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79260/4918 "Are Jedi required to abstain from all sexual relations, or only from the ones involving emotional attachments?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jedi are allowed to have sex, they aren't allowed to have an attachments - make of that what you will.

Quoting Mr. Lucas [himself](http://www.imdb.com/news/ni0058482/):

> Jedi Knights have sex after all, according to George Lucas, creator of
>   the characters' hit sci-fi series Star Wars. Speculation that the
>   lightsaber-wielding warriors were supposed to live a monk-like
>   existence has been rife since details of Attack Of The Clones began to
>   leak out. In the new flick Jedi Anakin Skywalker's character shares
>   forbidden love with Queen Amidala, but Lucas says it's romance, rather
>   than hanky panky, which is banned by the Jedi code. He says, "Jedi
>   Knights aren't celibate - the thing that is forbidden is attachments -
>   and possessive relationships." No Jedi Knight has yet been seen with a
>   partner in any of the five Star Wars movies.

Comment: Force ability is heritable. If Jedi didn't reproduce, it probably would have been bred out of the gene pool, or at least strong Force ability would be greatly reduced.

Comment: @pleurocoelus Turns out every force sensitive kid brought into the order is really a little Jedi bastard... Obi-wan getting down and dirty with a Hutt sex slave... Yoda using the force to get funky with a Twilek dancer... stay tuned to Imperial News as more Jedi sexual misconduct is discovered!