# What happens if a Jedi Accidentally has a Child?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

Okay, reading this question:  [Are Jedi required to abstain from all sexual relations, or only from the ones involving emotional attachments?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79260/are-jedi-required-to-abstain-from-all-sexual-relations-or-only-from-the-ones-in), the answer states per Lucas:

> "Jedi Knights aren't celibate - the thing that is forbidden is attachments - and possessive relationships."

Okay, so if they aren't necessarily celibate, what happens when there's an accidental pregnancy?  I mean, come on, let's be honest:  it does happen in the real world.

So I'm wondering:  if a Jedi were to engage in sexual congress, and a pregnancy occurred, would there be a punishment to the Jedi?  Would the pregnancy be allowed to come to term?  Force Abortion?

Absolutely ANY canon would work, but I doubt there is any, since this is probably too touchy a subject to be discussed outside of fanfics.  (Also, please do not write a fanfic about Force Abortions if you were inspired to do so by this question.)

Comment: *"Oops, I tripped and accidentally fathered a child"*

Comment: @Valorum Wasn't Ki-Adi Mundi allowed to have children as his race was endangered?

Comment: @cbredlow - He was indeed. But not an accident.

Comment: One hour ago I posted this question, and yet, not a single comment on Force Abortion?  Honestly, people:  stop being so proper.

Comment: The child grows up and destroys the Death Star?

Comment: Pay child support, you must.

Comment: “come on, let's be honest: it does happen in the real world” — was anyone saying it doesn’t happen in the real world?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well, my mom claimed I wasn't an accident, but we all knew better; does that count?  But anyway, I meant it in the sense that I was pointing out they would likely have an established protocol to deal with the situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are only a few Jedi who had children in all of canon and Legends. The following are the ones I am aware of who had children while under the authority of the Jedi Council<sup>1</sup>:

### Anakin Skywalker

The Jedi Council (what was left of it) did not find out about Skywalker's children, Luke and Leia, until after the Jedi Order was destroyed (the twins were born right at the end of the Clone Wars). Consequently, we do not know how the Council would have reacted if it had found out earlier. On the one hand, Skywalker's obvious anger issues might have caused the Council to act; on the other hand, it's unlikely the Council would do much to one of their most seasoned fighters so late in the Clone Wars.

### [Ki-Adi Mundi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi/Legends)

Mundi and was allowed to have multiple wives and children due to the low birth rates of his species, the [Cereans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cerean/Legends). I'm sure it also helped that he happened to be a member of the Jedi Council. He *was* required not to get too attached to his family, as <s>unrealistic</s> difficult as that must have been.

### [Quinlan Vos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Quinlan_Vos/Legends)

Vos had a son named [Korto Vos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Korto_Vos) after the Clone Wars ended and the Jedi Order was destroyed. We do not know what the Jedi Council would have done, since it no longer existed.

### [Nejaa Halcyon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nejaa_Halcyon)

Halcyon had a son named [Hal Horn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hal_Horn), who was even trained as a Padawan by his father. Halycon kept Horn's paternity a secret from the Council, though, so we don't know what repercussions Halcyon would have faced.<sup>2</sup>

### [Ranik Solusar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ranik_Solusar#Master_and_son)

Solusar was a Jedi Master who married and had a son against the will of the Jedi Council. He was reprimanded by the Council but he was not expelled from the Order (and the Council did not attempt to force an abortion).

### [Etain Tur-Mukan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Etain_Tur-Mukan#Mission_on_Coruscant)

Tur-Mukan had a son, [Venku Skirata](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Venku_Skirata), by clone commando [RC-1136/IC-1136 "Darman Skirata"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darman_Skirata). Aside from Anakin Skywalker, this is probably the closest case of an *accidental* pregnancy, since it's unlikely Tur-Mukan consciously chose to get pregnant while both she and her lover were fighting in the Clone Wars. However, the Jedi Council never found out about this pregnancy so it's not clear how the Council might have acted.

### Summary

Note that while several of the aforementioned characters exist in canon, in some cases their children exist only in Legends. Anakin Skywalker is the only Jedi in the above list with children who exist in canon. Since the Jedi Council was unaware of his children until the Jedi Order was destroyed, **from a canon point of view we do not know what the Jedi Council would have done with a Jedi who conceived a child.**

Even when we include Legends, most Jedi who had children hid it and therefore we don't know what the Jedi Council would have done in those cases. Some, like Ki-Adi Mundi, <s>had the right connections and</s> were given exceptions and allowed to have children. Others were reprimanded but ultimately allowed to have the child and even remain in the Order. Therefore, **from a Legends point of view, the Jedi Council's punishment for a Jedi who conceived a child was light: at worst, the Jedi would receive a reprimand but would be allowed to remain in the Order.**

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that other Jedi had children while *not* under the authority of the Jedi Council. For example, the Jedi Knights [Kento Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kento_Marek) and [Mallie Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mallie_Marek) had a son named [Galen Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek). However, Kento and Mallie went into self-imposed exile before marrying and conceiving Galen. Since they left the Order, the Jedi Council had no power over them and I exclude them from the above list. (Incidentally, they also survived Order 66 primarily because they had already left the Jedi Order.)

<sup>2</sup>It might seem implausible that the Jedi were unaware of a father training his own son right under their noses, but these were the same Jedi so blind that they couldn't detect the Sith Lord in their midst as Supreme Chancellor of the Republic.

Comment: What about the father of Starkiller? (Vaders "secret" apprentice) Of course that was after order 66 too so no jedi council to answer to

Comment: would it be too much to ask for an asterisk or something denoting which of the responses in the list above are official canon vs legends? (specifically wondering about Vos - I suspect that is non-Disney canon)

Comment: Ranik Solusar would be the closest out of this list, since the Order still existed.  So basically, the Jedi Council were all bark, no bite on that.

Comment: @MichaelBrown His parents left the Jedi Order before they had him. I added a note about him but he's not on my main list.

Comment: @NKCampbell I added a note at the end that only Anakin has children in canon.

Comment: Was this order in effect (in Legends canon) at the time of Nomi Sunrider? I recall she was married and had a kid.

Comment: @MarkEdward I'm not sure. I've heard the name before but I'm not that familiar with the character. I didn't notice any objections by the other Jedi in her Wookieepedia article, so that rule might not have been in effect (or just not enforced).

Comment: @Null since this answer is a mix of legends and canon, it would be nice if you identified the canon and legends material.  From what canon material I've read, only Anakin had children in canon, but I've missed enough books and other material that I'm not sure if there is anything else canon in this answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The second sentence after the "Summary" heading has the information you're looking for: Anakin Skywalker is the only Jedi in the above list with children who exist in canon."