# Which known Jedi have engaged in casual sex?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi

With reference to [Are Jedi required to abstain from all sexual relations, or only from the ones involving emotional attachments?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79260/are-jedi-required-to-abstain-from-all-sexual-relations-or-only-from-the-ones-in)

Jedi are not permitted to form attachments but they are not required to be celibate. So to use Anakin Skywalker as an example, he is permitted to have sex with Padme if he chooses to but he is not permitted to be engaged in a long-term romantic relationship with her.

Now, casual sex has no emotional attachments to it by definition. So technically Jedi are permitted to engage in that if they want to. Are there any Jedi known to have actually done so? Anakin doesn't count because it most certainly isn't casual.

Comment: "Now, casual sex has no emotional attachments to it by definition." I think the Jedi order may think otherwise. I also think a lot of people on our own planet may think otherwise. Perhaps backing it up with a source of definition may help because the answer really depends on it.

Comment: Did any Legends material involve prostitution in any way? If a Jedi ever patronized such a service or even worked as a prostitute, it would count, I would think. The Star Wars universe includes sexual slavery so surely voluntary prostitution would not be unreasonable.

Comment: Great questions like this make me sad that Star Wars is getting Disney-washed. I think the SW universe is in a great place to explore the ethics of sexuality, slavery, and some others, but of course they won't under Disney's direction.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I wouldn't say so. The Disney novel *Lords of the Sith* has a former sex slave as a main character, and the topic is definitely explored.

Comment: I have no evidence, but you can't tell me Mace Windu wasn't a complete Mack Daddy.

Comment: Now, I see why Cardinals go for casual sex all the time..

Comment: @user931 too soon.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, casual sex have been very limited in *Star Wars*, at least for Jedi. Jedi Padawan Kira Carsen mentions that, ''The [Jedi] Council can grant Jedi the right to 'attach' under certain circumstances . . . only Jedi who were raised by the order from birth get permission.'' Though any such relationship, formally declared, will be heavily monitored, reviewed monthly. The two would be kept apart from each other and only allowed to meet on occassion.

Though all player-based decisions, there are many such options in *Star Wars: The Old Republic*.

Most of these romances can be seen in: [here](https://youtu.be/5GjVADOTwqk).

- Ki Sazen, a fallen Jedi Knight, can have casual sex once with the male Imperial Agent Cipher Nine.
- Any male Republic aligned character; including Jedi Knight & Jedi Consular, can have casual sex once with a civilian Deera Ulyette.
- The player-controlled female Jedi Knight can have casual sex multiple times with Doctor Archiban Frodrick Kimble (a.k.a.: Doc).
- The player-controlled male Jedi Knight can have casual sex with Jedi Padawan Kira Carsen once, then the relationship complicates due to not qualifying the ''Jedi relationship'' requirements where the choice to continue or not is presented.
- The player-controlled female Jedi Consular can have casual sex with Republic soldier Lieutenant Felix Iresso once.
- Though arguable if emotionless, the player-controlled male Jedi Knight can have relatively casual sex once with a civilian Ranna Tao'ven.
- The player-controlled female Jedi Consular can have casual sex with Doctor Tharan Cedrax once, a person who is in a semi-committed relationship with a sentient A.I..

  There can be some more romances hiding in the expansions.

Other than in *Star Wars: The Old Republic*, one or twice I know of is:

- Jedi Knight Etain Tur-Mukan, who was in a relationship with a clone commando, likely only had casual sex. But then, the commando did ignore Order 66 for her.
- The fallen Jedi Darth Raven as a brainwashed Jedi Knight, once more, can have a ''massage'' from female slaves only in *Star Wars: Knights of the old Republic*. Though not known exactly what the massage entail; there is that innuendo.

Comment: A screenshot of said dialogue choices, as well as what follows, could probably make for a greater answer, even if the "canonicity" of TOR might be subject to debate :)

Comment: I wouldn't say there are "many" options in SWTOR. There's one (optional) instance of casual sex early in the Jedi Knight's storyline which is considered a Dark Side action *because* it involves an emotional commitment. On the other hand, a female Jedi Consular can strike up a casual relationship with companion Tharan Cedrax which is, however, torpedoed by his sapient AI assistant. (Long story.) Other than those, the only encounters I can recall are as part of long-term romance arcs.